# Isotope - change filter option on filter button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am using isotope on a page with 2 group filters, here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K8QN6/),
and I am trying to add an extra functionality, if the filter button is pressed the second time, when it has the "selected" class on it, the list should reset itself and display all the elements again. I tried to do it using the 'reLayout' method.

Like this:

```
  if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
      $container.isotope( 'reLayout' );
    return;
  }
```

but it's not working and I have no clue why.

Does anyone has a better idea on how to make this work ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After many try-outs I've managed to do this.

Here is my solution in case anyone will have the same need

The updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/K8QN6/2/

```
$('.filter a').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    // don't proceed if already selected

    var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
    // change selected class
    $this.toggleClass('selected');

    // store filter value in object
    // i.e. filters.color = 'red'
    var group = $optionSet.attr('data-filter-group');
    filters[group] = $this.attr('data-filter-value');

    // convert object into array
    var isoFilters = [];
    for (var prop in filters) {
        isoFilters.push(filters[prop])
    }
    var selector = isoFilters.join('');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: selector
    });

    if (!$this.hasClass('selected')) {
        $this.attr("data-filter-value", $this.data("filter-value"));
    } else {
        $this.data("filter-value", $this.attr("data-filter-value"));            
        $this.attr("data-filter-value", "");
    }

    return false;
});
```